# How to generate mapping.txt using Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I read from Android developers [page](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) & other pages on web. But I couldn't find a way to generate mapping.txt from Eclipse.

If Eclipse is generating this file, where is it keeping this?

I have *project.properties*:

```
target=android-14
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

And *proguard.cfg*:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

*.project* and *.classpath*.

Comment: did you get the solution for the above question please help i am stuck with the same.

Answer (score 5):

The current version of the Eclipse plugin (20.0.0) by default lets ProGuard write out the mapping file as `proguard/mapping.txt` (when exporting an apk).

The Ant build process by default lets ProGuard write out the mapping file as `bin/proguard/mapping.txt` (when creating a release build).

Cfr. Android SDK docs > Develop > Tools > ProGuard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I solved it. Just add these line in Proguard.cfg and you will get **Proguard** named folder in your project folder:

```
-dump proguard/class_files.txt 
-printseeds proguard/seeds.txt 
-printusage proguard/unused.txt 
-printmapping proguard/mapping.txt
```

Hope this helps someone.